# setup_requires only for some commands

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I have a distutils-style Python package which requires a specific, and quite large, dependency for its build step. Currently, this dependency is specified under the `setup_requires` argument to distutils.setup. Unfortunately, this means the dependency will be built for *any* execution of setup.py, including when running `setup.py clean`. This creates the rather ironic situation of the clean step sometimes causing large amount of code to be compiled.

As I said, this setup dependency is only required for the `build` step. Is there a way to encode this logic in setup.py so that all commands that do not invoke the build command are run without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always order the `Distribution` to fetch some packages explicitly, same way as they will be if you define them in `setup_requires`. Example with `numpy` dependency required for `build` command only:

```python
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig
from setuptools import setup, find_packages,  Command, dist


class build(build_orig):

    def run(self):
        self.distribution.fetch_build_eggs(['numpy'])
        # numpy becomes available after this line. Test it:
        import numpy
        print(numpy.__version__)
        super().run()

setup(
    name='spam',
    packages=find_packages(),
    cmdclass={'build': build,}
    ...
)
```

The dependencies are passed the same as they would be defined in `setup_requires` arg, so version specs are also ok:

```
self.distribution.fetch_build_eggs(['numpy>=1.13'])
```

Although I must note that fetching dependencies via `setup_requires` is usually *much* slower than installing them via `pip` (especially when you have some heavy dependencies that must be built from source first), so if you can be sure you will have `pip` available ([or use `python3.4` and newer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#module-ensurepip)), the approach suggested by [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48284235/2650249) will save you time. Fetching eggs via distribution may, however, come handy when building for old python versions or obscure python installations like the system python on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
if sys.argv[0] == 'build':
    kw = {'setup_requires': [req1, req2, …]}
else:
    kw = {}

setup(
    …,
    **kw
)
```

Another approach to try is override `build` command with a custom `cmdclass`:

```
from setuptools.command.build import build as _build

class build(_build):
    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(["pip", "install", req1, req2…])
        _build.run(self)

setup(
    …,
    cmdclass={'build': build},
)
```

and avoid `setup_requires` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately that fails when the build command is invoked as a sub-command of something else. (e.g.: When running `python setup.py install`.)

Comment: I added another approach to the answer.